# In which children div Jquery is adding the class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code snippet but I am not understanding in which children element the jquery script is adding class as I have never used the .children() method before Here is the HTML :

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="click"></div>
  <div id="fc-wrapper" class="fc-wrapper">
    <!-- right-most handle piece -->
    <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-pull"></div>
    <div class="fc-perspective">
      <!-- right part overlay; get's darker -->
      <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-reverse"></div>
      <!-- middle handle piece -->
      <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-out">
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- inner bottom content part -->
      <div class="fc-bottom">
        <div class="fc-bottom-bg">
          <div class="fc-content">
            <p>I can live with doubt, and uncertainty, and not knowing. I think it's much more interesting to live not knowing than to have answers which might be wrong. <span>Richard Feynman</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-solid"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- //fc-bottom -->
      <!-- front and back of the flipping half -->
      <div class="fc-flip">
        <div class="fc-front">
          <div class="fc-inner">
            <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-left"></div>
            <!-- left-most part of handle -->
            <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-in">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-content">
              <h3><span>♞</span>Free revelations</h3>
              <p>by NYCL</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //fc-front -->
        <div class="fc-back">
          <div class="fc-inner">
            <div class="fc-content">
              <div class="feynman">
                <span>1918 &ndash; 1988</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-right"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //fc-back -->
      </div>
      <!-- //fc-flip -->
    </div>
    <!-- //fc-perspective -->
  </div>
  <!-- //fc-wrapper -->
</section>
```

And here is theJQUERY code :

```
$(function() {          
    var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
        $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );                

    $handle.on( 'click', function( event ) {                
        ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();                
    } );

    $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
        switch( event.direction ) {
            case 'right': open(); break;
            case 'left': close(); break;
        }
    });

    function open() {
        $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', true );
    }

    function close() {
        $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', false );
        }

});
```

I want to know in which child JQUERY is adding the 'fc-wrapper-open' class . Please help me . Thanks in advance .

Comment: It isn't adding the class to any children at all, but to the variable `$wrapper`, which is explicitly set at the top to the `#fc-wrapper` element

Comment: Is it changing the class from #fc-wrapper to  #fc-wrapper-open ? Thanks for your replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*which children element the jquery script is adding class*

Not to any child `div`. because of a var declared at

```
var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ), // <-----here
    $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );
```

and you are trying to add the class on the wrapper element which is not the descendant element *child* but the ancestor *parent* of the clicked element.

You can take a look at your event handler:

```
$handle.on( 'click', function( event ) {                
    ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();                
});
```

At above click handler you can see it is using a ternary operation to call two functions `close()` and `open()` but first it checks the `data` of your selector `$handle` which is your `'div.fc-handle-pull'` div.

When it tries to find the `data` in the ternary operator as `true` `close()` is called which causes to remove the added class. if `false` then it causes to add the class.

```
function open() {
    $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' ); // adding the class
    $handle.data( 'opened', true ); // setting a data to true to call the 
}                                   // close() when click again

function close() {
    $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' ); // removing the class
    $handle.data( 'opened', false ); // setting the data to false to call the
}                                    // open() again when clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is adding the `fc-wrapper-open` class to your fc-wrapper div. Take a look at the code:

`var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' )`

now `$wrapper` is a variable that points to your fc-wrapper div

```
function open() {
    $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
    $handle.data( 'opened', true );
}
```

this simply adds a class called `'fc-wrapper-open'` to your fc-wrapper div

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you are adding this class by `$wrapper.addClass`. `$wrapper` is specified in start of JS code `$wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),`. And your element `#fc-wrapper` is `section > div#fc-wrapper` (second div inside `<section class="main">`

Answer (score 0):

The function open is adding the class fc-wrapper-open to fc-wrapper div

```
function open() {
    $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
    $handle.data( 'opened', true );
}
```